# Optional parameters and date index

Tags: t-sql, indexing

I'm playing around with two very simple queries.  There is a non-clustered index with `StartDate` and `EndDate`, as well as `Id` as an included column.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
SELECT @startDate = '4/1/2011', @endDate = '5/1/2011'

-- Does Index Scan (slow)
SELECT Id
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE
    (@startDate IS NULL OR StartDate >= @startDate) AND
    (@endDate IS NULL OR EndDate < @endDate)

-- Does Index Seek (fast)
SELECT Id
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE
    (StartDate >= @startDate) AND
    (EndDate < @endDate)
```

Is there any way to rearrange, pre-calculate, or otherwise change the query to have an index seek occur in the first example?

**Edit:** I know this is a very basic indexing problem, but I haven't found a good solution yet.  Note that I am declaring the variables, but those would be parameters in an sproc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following?

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
SELECT @startDate = '4/1/2011', @endDate = '5/1/2011'

SELECT Id
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE
    StartDate >= ISNULL(@startDate, '1/1/1753') 
    AND
    EndDate < ISNULL(@endDate, '12/31/9999')
```

This code is probably broken if you have an end date of 12/31/9999 in your table that you *actually* want returned from your result set, but how often does that happen?

Comment: This isn't the same thing at all - anything with a NULL EndDate or StartDate would get excluded, which isn't the case with the OP's first query.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight: Right, in my case StartDate can't have nulls, but EndDate can, so this breaks.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight: Actually, it can't use `EndDate` as a seek predicate, but it can use `StartDate`, which still helps quite a bit.  Usually only recent entries are pulled, so that's already a huge help.  For the purpose of the original question and not my specific implementation, is it even possible to do this if `StartDate` were nullable?

Comment: It's also worth noting that `COALESCE` will not do an index seek like `ISNULL` does.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your original query will never return rows in which the EndDate column is NULL, since NULL is not greater than anything, including another NULL. @CodeByMoonlight, can you show that the answer query is "not the same thing at all" by supplying values for StartDate and EndDate columns and @StartDate and @EndDate parameters that would cause the original query and my answer query to return different results?

Comment: @Nelson Rothermel: If the EndDate column can contain NULL values, then I propose that your original query will only return them if the specified @EndDate value is also NULL. Is this the behavior you expect?

Comment: @John: Yes, that is the behavior I expect, hence the `(@endDate IS NULL OR EndDate < @endDate)`.  I think what @CodeByMoonlight is saying is that your `EndDate < ISNULL(@endDate, '12/31/9999')` will never return rows where `EndDate IS NULL`, while in my example, if `@endDate IS NULL`, all rows are returned.

Comment: @Nelson Rothermel: As you said, based on this condition I don't think you can get an index seek on the EndDate column, since it's nullable.